# 2D Drawing package for C#

Tags: c#, drawing

I'm looking for one package that allows me to draw some forms as rectangles, circles, etc. in 2D. I'm looking for one package similar to HelixToolKit but just in 2D.

Can enybody help me?

Comment: Define *some stuff*. Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this.

https://github.com/nakov/TurtleGraphics.NET

Appears to be similar to pythons turtle.